# HTML Input Divided Into 12 columns

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Can we create a input field like in the image using only one input field in angularjs. Each box should allow only one number.

[image]

```
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>
<li><input type="text" maxlength="1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,$(this))"></li>

function isNumber(evt,ele) {
evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
}
if(ele.val().length == 0){
    ele.parent().next().children('input').focus();
}


  return true;
}
```

I did using twelve input boxes. Is there any other way to do it.
I also need to avoid using jquery.

Comment: You could keep the 12 input boxes and attach an `ng-model="numberArray[position]"` directive to each, which would store all numbers in an array for further processing.

Comment: Was going to do that only, just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried to user ng-repeat? Also why don't you use `ngKeyPress`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not.

But you can improve your implementation by improving backspace/typing convenience for the user.

Here is an example:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('myInputWrapper');

var numberOfInputs = 12;
var inputList = [];

for(var i=0; i<numberOfInputs; i++){
 var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "text";
  input.setAttribute('data-number', i+1);
 inputList.push(input);
 wrapper.appendChild(input);
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  // If backspace
  if(isBackspace(e)){
     if(this.value.length == 0){
      var previus = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-number')) - 2;
       if(previus >= 0){
      inputList[previus].focus();
       }
      }
      return true;
    }
    // If isNumber
   else if(isNumber(e)){
     if(this.value.length > 0){
       this.value = this.value[this.value.length - 1];
        var next = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-number'));
        if(next < numberOfInputs){
         if(inputList[next].length > 0)
           inputList[next].value = "";
          inputList[next].focus();
        } else {
         this.value = "";
        }
      }
     return true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
  }, false);
  // Put curet on the end
  input.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   this.value = this.value;
  }, false);
  // oh.. someone has paste something
  input.addEventListener('paste', function(e){

 // Get Text
 var pastedText = undefined;
 if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
   pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
 } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
   pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
 }
 
 // Error?
 if(!pastedText) return;
 
 var digits = pastedText.match(/\d/g);
 
 // No digits
 if(!digits) return;
 
 var data = [];
 for(var i=0; i<digits.length; i++){
   data.push(parseInt(digits[i]));
 };
 
 updateInputs(data);
 
 e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}

function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 8) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function isBackspace(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 8) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function updateInputs (array){
 for(var i=0; i<array.length && i<numberOfInputs; i++)
   inputList[i].value = ("" + array[i])[0];
  for(var i=array.length; i<numberOfInputs; i++)
   inputList[i].value = "";
}

function getInputs (array){
 var data = [];
 for(var i=0; i<numberOfInputs; i++)
   if(inputList[i].value.length == 1)
    data.push(inputList[i].value);
    else
     data.push(null);
  return data;
}


document.getElementById('testInsert').addEventListener('click', function(){
 updateInputs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]);
}, false);
document.getElementById('testExtract').addEventListener('click', function(){
 alert(getInputs());
}, false);
```

```css
#myInputWrapper input{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
}
#myInputWrapper input:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myInputWrapper"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Test Data Insert" id="testInsert">
<input type="button" value="Test Data Extract" id="testExtract">
```

And here too:
https://jsfiddle.net/cbh0f3xe/1/

**Edit**
Paste support added.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better implementation. Working great in pc.
But moving the focus to next input is not working in mobile chrome browser. On inspecting I found the charCode in isNumber function is always 229. Do you know how we can get around this?

Comment: Maybe you need to change the keydown event to keyup or something.